# Spaces in PATH npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path, gulp

So I've been trying to install `gulp` and I keep getting:

> module.js:471^throw err : cannot find module 'C:\c\Users\Joe's Steezy
>   Laptop\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\bin\gulp.js'

As you can see my `username` has spaces in it and I read that `npm` cant read paths that have spaces. my question is how do i fix this? I know theres the option to do `symbolic links`, and there is an option to make a whole new user and make sure the username folder doesn't have any spaces in it this time.

Is there another way I can do this? I don't trust myself enough to do a `symbolic link` because i read that it can really mess up your system if you mess it up. I also don't really want to make a whole new user on my laptop because then i have to install all my programs all over again which kind of sucks. Please if anyone can help, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

This is for those who all are facing the issue and didn't get any workaround. What you can do is change the cache path using below command:

> npm config set cache "C:\Users\FirstName~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global

Here **FirstName** is path name which includes spaces between them.

Answer (score 4):

This works for `windows`. You can use the short path name in the environment variable, e.g. use `"C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs"` instead of `"C:\Progam Files\nodejs"`.

You can find out the correct short name of your folder by executing `dir /x` in the parent folder.

Comment: I'm still kind of new to all of this, where would the parent folder be? I just want to get the right because its taken me 3 days to figure this out and im super behind on my project.

Comment: I just did the C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs and my nodejs files came up. So would that be the parent variable?

Comment: The issue is the Folder name "Joe's Steezy Laptop' I think thats where it fails

Comment: I gave an example with `program files`. Just got to `\c\Users` folder and execute this command you will get short name for your username folder . just replace it.

Comment: parent dorectory is the folder which contains your required folder, here `users` folder contains `Joe's Steezy Laptop` folder, so `users` is the parent directory  of `Joe's Steezy Laptop`.

Comment: This answer was useful for me.