# Npm modules not getting installed and throws this error: 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I went to my github repository of a few months old project. At that time, it was working quite alright.

When I tried to `npm install`, I can see the `node modules` folder. Then I have these `npm error`

[image]

Then when I tried, to `npm start` it shows this error:

```
'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

and then the  `node modules` are deleted. The file would just disappear.

This is the package.json:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command

```
npm install react-scripts --save
```

Comment: I tried this and the same thing still happens. It throws off an error and then the node modules disappears again

Answer (score 0):

`npm` has problems reading paths with spaces.

You should change the path either by directly **removing the spaces** or **replacing them** with some other characters for example `_`, `-`, etc.

After that, you should be able to run `npm install` successfully and then `npm start`.

Also you can change the cache path like this: [Spaces in PATH npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871452/spaces-in-path-npm)

Comment: I tried changing the path name and it won't work